# CA1063 Remove finalizer from class and add it in the code where disposing is false

Tags: c#, interop, fxcop

I have been trying to avoid this warning, what I have tried and understand according to [CA1063: Implement IDisposable correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1063?view=vs-2019) is that the finalizer should just include the Dispose method in false. And the rest of the code should be written somewhere else. I tried implement like, the example from Microsoft, but when I add the Dispose method, appears an error saying that the dispose method already exists, the only Dispose that already exists its in the Designer. Is the designer the one who is causing trouble?

```
~TimerUpdate()
{
    Dispose(false);
    try
    {
        this.matlab = null;
        this.command = null;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in " + this.GetType().Name + ".cs: " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "(): " + ex.Message);
        this.Dispose();
    }
}

private void TimerUpdate_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.updateRateBox_ValueChanged(sender, e);
        this.updateRateCAN_ValueChanged(sender, e);
        this.matlab = null;
        this.Dispose();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in " + this.GetType().Name + ".cs: " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "(): " + ex.Message);
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to move the Dispose() from the designer.cs file into the main code file for that class. If you check the "designer.cs" file you can see that the Dispose() is OUTSIDE the "Windows Form Designer generated code" section, so it's safe to move. I move the Dispose() method out from the designer file every time I create a control/form - I wish there was a setting for that so I didn't have to do myself all the time!

Comment: @MatthewWatson ok, perfect and the code in the finalizer should I just paste in that Dispose() ?

Comment: Yes, the finalizer should only call `Dispose(false)` and do nothing else. But you need to write the `protected virtual Dispose(bool)` method yourself, and then change `Dispose()` to call `Dispose(true)` - exactly like the sample code in the link you posted.

Comment: Does your class have native resources like `IntPtr` handles or managed resources like `FileStream`? If you only have managed resources you can override `Dispose()` and call `_resource?.Dispose()` on managed resources. There is no need for this pattern in this case. Am I right? @MatthewWatson

Comment: From Microsoft Docs: *NOTE: Leave out the finalizer altogether if this class doesn't own unmanaged resources, but leave the other methods exactly as they are.*

Comment: @N.Dogac it does not have native resources, only managed resources

Comment: @RendonLs Then you can leave out finalizer because GC tracks other managed objects and collects them.